# Not able to share the link in whatsapp which contains parameters in url

Tags: php, whatsapp

I have link which needs to be shared in whatsapp which looks like the one shown below.

```
<?php 
$temp = 'whatsapp://send?text=http://www.example.com/index.php?
           secid=1&url=/content/575098/ready-opposed.html';
?>

<a href="<?php echo urlencode($temp); ?>">
  <img src="img_uploads/watsapp.png" width="18" height="18"/>
</a>
```

So now when I share it through mobile site, in Whatsapp I get only **http://www.example.com/index.php?secid=1** but the next parameter url is not there. Just to test if I put url as 1st parameter and secid as 2nd parameter then I receive only url but not secid.

In my scenario only if those 2 parameters is present the page is rendered

Can someone please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Just Use The rawurlencode() instead of urlencode()
For example

```
<?php
$value = 2;
$text = rawurlencode("www.domain.com/products.php?Id=".$value);
?>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo $text; ?>"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm reviving an old/dead answer, but I had the same problem and solved URLencoding the special chars.

In this case, `convert the & with %26`

Some ref:

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem using:

```
$value = 2;
$message_to_send = urlencode(rawurlencode("www.domain.com/products.php?Id=".$value))
```